# How to write a function that returns an array of all values of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stuck on an assignment and I need help. I know that my title for this post does not make sense so I will try to explain it the best that I can. this is the simple assignment that I had to do:

Write a function called getValues. This function should:
accept one argument, an object
return an array of each of the values in the object. Also it must return an empty array if no values or valus exist exists.

The function must return the vaules of {name: "Rob", age: 25}

I wrote the function and it worked. Here it is:

```
var name = ("Rob");
var age = (25);

var getValues = function() {
return [name, age];
};
```

The problem is the if I write the function to return an empty array it works but my previous function fails or stops running.

My question is there a way to write this simple code so that both functions work? Is there a way to write this function to preform both tasks? I am a beginner and I agreatly appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: `const getValues = obj => Object.values(obj);` ??

Comment: I regret to say that this question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Hint: `getValues` should take an object argument. Your code will get you a fail.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is you don't need a separate function to handle the empty array case. You instead have one function named `getValues` that uses an `if else` statement to handle the two different cases.

JavaScript provides a built in handler that will allow you to pull the values off an object.

```
function getValues(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj);
}
```

You will need to handle the case where obj is undefined, otherwise the code will throw an error. Rather than defining a separate function with the same name, we use an if statement to capture the undefined case.

```
function getValues(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    return [];
  }

  return Object.values(obj);
}
```

Comment: Emand thanks for explaining this to me. I starting to understand things better thanks to you. You have given a better explanation then the bootcamp I am attending. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find answers useful on StackOverflow, please upvote them and, if somebody gives you the answer you want, accept their answers. It helps future users find relevant information in a quicker and clearer manner.